# How can I get a list of active processes using PowerSNMP for .NET?

Tags: c#, snmp, mib, dart-communications

I would like to user dart PowerSNMP for .NET to retrieve a list of all the processes and their respective pids and write them to the Visual Studio console whenever I receive a message in event. I assume this is done by walking the mib tree and then retrieving the actual values of a specific OID but I'm not too clear on how all this works.

For instance, assuming I have an agent that receives messages like so.

```
private void agent1_MessageReceived(Agent agent, RequestMessage request, object state)
{
        //print the processes and pids using power snmp
        String process = "";

        //concat processes and pids
                 ....


        Console.WriteLine(process);

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library (or any other SNMP libraries) won't help you do all the tasks.

You have to implement the [Host Resources MIB](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2790) in your agent, so that the `hrSWRunTable` can then be queried by an SNMP manager,

http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/mibs/host.html#hrSWRunTable

To implement this table, you can use `Process.GetProcesses` as Charles indicated.

About how to extend PowerSNMP's agent, you can refer to its source code and also Dart's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

there is a function in .Net framework (System.Diagnostics.Process)

remember to include: `using System.Diagnostics;`

[Process.GetProcesses();](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9(v=vs.110).aspx)

that returns an array of processes

Comment: I need to do this with the PowerSNMP for .NET library.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with that library, Since .Net is a framework library  based system,  I just assumed it must have a mechanism that allows it to call built in framework code like other .Net languages.